# How to get back to the for loop after exception handling

Tags: python, exception

I am ready to run this code but before I want to fix the exception handling:

```
for l in bios:
    OpenThisLink = url + l
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(OpenThisLink)
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        pass
    bio = response.read()
    item = re.search('(JD)(.*?)(\d+)', bio)
    ....
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817815/what-are-these-errors-and-how-do-i-handle-them), I added the `try...except` but now if a page doesn't open I get this error:

```
bio = response.read()
NameError: name 'response' is not defined
```

So the program continues to execute. Instead I want it to go back to the for loop and try the next url. I tried `break` instead of `pass` but that ends the program. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `continue` instead of `break`.

The statement `pass` is a no-op (meaning that it doesn't do anything). The program just continues to the next statement, which is why you get an error.

`break` exits the loops and continues running from the next statement immediately after the loop. In this case, there are no more statements, which is why your program terminates.

`continue` restarts the loop but with the next item. This is exactly what you want.

Comment: After an exception is handled it returns to where it was caught, just like most burglers.

Comment: @jathanism: no, it doesn't. If you don't `raise` it again or something, it continues to the statement after the `except` block.

Answer (score 20):

Try is actually way more powerful than that. You can use the else block here too:

```
try:
    stuff
except Exception:
    print "oh no a exception"
else:
    print "oh yay no exception"
finally:
    print "leaving the try block"
```

Comment: The else statement is useful in general but the else code ends up being indented when for most normal situations (ie no exception) this code runs.  In your situation continue means "skip the rest of the loop on exception" which is the intended functionality and so continue is more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that error because when the exception is thrown the response variable doesn't exist.  If you want to leave the code how you have it you will need to check that response exists before calling read

```
if response:
    bio = response.read()
    ...
```

having said that I agree with Mark that `continue` is a better suggestion than `pass`